# Adding to an existing String Value

Tags: excel, string, vba

So in a document I wish to convert a column of letters into a single cell. For example if the column contained the letters h,e,l,l,o then the program would put into a single cell "hello". I attempted to do this with the following code but it leaves the output cell blank

```
Dim t1 As String
Dim t2 As String

Do While Cells(i, "B").Value <> ""
t2 = Cells(i, "D").Value
t1 = Cells(i, "B").Value
Cells(i, "D").Value = t1 & t2
i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Office 365 exel: `=CONCAT(B1:B5)`

Answer (score 3):

```
Function MyConcat(rng as range)
    dim rngEach as Range
    For Each rngEach in rng            
        MyConcat = MyConcat & rngEach.Value      
    Next rngEach
End Function
```

Then in the cell put: `=MyConcat(B1:B5)`

[image]

Comment: Discarding blanks would be appropriate if you were adding a delimiter however.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use VBA for this. Excel has built in function `CONCATENATE()`.

Use it like this:

In the cell where you need the output enter the formula

```
=CONCATENATE(Select cell 1, select cell2,select cell3)
```

So you can select all the cells which you want to join. Put a comma in between each cell.